# Covert std::string(utf8) to std::string(MultiByte) in C++

Tags: c++, android-ndk, stdstring, multibyte, utf8-decode

Data Source By TinyXML,

```
 Data encoding(UTF-8)

std::string sAnswer = pStageNode->ToElement()->Attribute("Answer");
```

I want to covert `std::string(utf8)` to `std::string(MultiByte)`

and My Platform is Android(NDK)

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "MultiByte"?  UTF-8 is already a multibyte character encoding.

Comment: UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding. I think you need to say what *encoding* you wish to convert to. Maybe MultiByte means something special in the Android environment?